# Login form using JQuery ajax MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

Hel me please.At the moment i am working at a MVC project in C#.I created a pop-up register form, but can not create a pop up login form which redirect me to the another page(personal room for exemple).I watched many videos and read but nothing relevant.Can you help me with suggesting any code (controller, view) or link material where I can create a popup login form using Jquery,ajax.Please...Thankyou

Comment: Hey there! Are you wanting help with the 'pop-up' and the ajax form? Or are you just wanting help with the javascript?

Comment: Doesn't matter mate, anything but better  is jquery because i work with bootstrap

Comment: John, can you help me with this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612282/mvc-modal-login-using-jquery-ajax-asp-net/62612298#62612298, i appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery and HTML here's what the basic structure should look like.

You can test it on this dummy API with the username 'eve.holt@reqres.in' and password 'cityslicka'.

**HTML**

```
<div> 
   <input type="text" id="user">
   <input type="password" id="password">
   <button id="submit-button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#submit-button').click(function(){
  var username = $('#user').val()
  var password = $('#password').val()
  $.post( 
    "https://reqres.in/api/login", 
    { email: username, password: password })
    .done(function( data ) {
      console.log(data)
      //save the token to your cookies and redirect
    });
})
```